# MySQLの文字変換のエラーでデータが挿入できない

Tags: mysql, aws-cloud9

## 背景

MySQLで以下のようなテーブルを作成し、日本語でデータを挿入しようとしています。
実装環境はAWS Cloud9とmysql5.7.33です。

```
CREATE TABLE note (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  title VARCHAR(100)
);
```

## 問題

以下のようにデータを挿入しようとすると、文字変換のエラーが表示され、解決方法がわかりません。

```sql
mysql> INSERT INTO note (title) VALUES("Python入門");
ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect string value: '\xE5\x85\xA5\xE9\x96\x80' for column 'title' at row 1
mysql> show variables like "chara%";
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | latin1                     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

## 試したこと

以下の文字列変換対策コマンドを実行し、mysqlは再起動して、上記の`utf8`が反映されていることを確認しました。

```sh
$ sed -e "/utf8/d" -e "/client/d" -e "/^\[mysqld_safe\]$/i character-set-server=utf8\n\n[client]\ndefault-character-set=utf8" /etc/my.cnf |sudo tee /etc/my.cnf
$ sudo service mysqld restart
```

## 開発環境

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.33, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CREATE TABLE` 時に `CHARSET utf8mb4` を指定すればいいと思います。
テーブルを作成する毎にいちいち指定するのが面倒な場合は、`CREATE DATABASE` 時に `CHARSET utf8mb4` を指定しておけばいいです。
https://www.slideshare.net/tmtm/mysql-2017 このスライドが参考になるかも知れません。

Answer (score 0):

`mysql> show variables like "chara%";`の結果に、
`character_set_database`と`character_set_server`はまだlatin1ですね。
それらもutf8にしてみたら？